# C# DateTime.ParseExact for "2012-09-03T06:35:31Z"

Tags: c#, datetime

In C# I am trying to convert "2012-09-03T06:35:31Z" into a Datetime:

```
Date = DateTime.ParseExact( "2012-09-03T06:35:31Z", ???);
```

I'm not sure how to parse the rest of the function

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The documentation is pretty good: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx

Comment: What's wrong with simply `DateTime.Parse("2012-09-03T06:35:31Z")`?

Comment: Check out well known date time formats at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx and see if any work for you.

Comment: Is the Z guaranteed to always be there (and hence the date-time always UTC), of is it to be there when appropriate (UTC) with other timezone designators used for other timezones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//using System.Globalization; should be at top

Date = DateTime.ParseExact("2012-09-03T06:35:31Z", "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss'Z'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal)
```

See the [custom date and time format documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4).  This is similar to the [sortable format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#Sortable), but with a Z on the end.

Comment: Similar, but not the same, as they're both different ISO 8601 profiles.

Comment: Hm, yeah, after another glance at the list, it's actually closer to sortable than round-trip, so I noted that instead.  Not really important anyway, I just mentioned it since that's how I got the string at first to change it.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say whether the format is specified as always being in UTC and indicated with `Z`.

If that is the case, then

```
DateTime.ParseExact(
  yourDateString, @"yyyy\-MM\-ddTHH:mm:ss\Z",
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal)
```

Will do fine.

However, if UTC is not specified by the standard you are working to, the input you have to deal with could also be e.g. `2012-09-03T06:35:31+05:00` or `2012-09-03T06:35:31+0500` depending on the ISO 8601 format in use - `Z` is a special case within that format for `+00:00`. If you need to handle that possibility, then you want to first create a `DateTimeOffset`, and then obtain the equivalent UTC `DateTime` from it:

```
DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(yourDateString,
  new string[]{@"yyyy\-MM\-ddTHH:mm:sszzz",@"yyyy\-MM\-ddTHH:mm:ss\Z"},
  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal).UtcDateTime
```

Note that we still use `AssumeUniversal`. This is because the second format is saying "A Z will appear here", but the method then ignores it, so we have to explicitly have this form interpreted as UTC. With the first format though, the `zzz` will give the timezone, and hence the `AssumeUniversal` is ignored. (Or to put it another way, it's assuming universal until told otherwise, and that format does indeed say otherwise).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to parse an Xml date.  If this is the case I would suggest using the XmlConvert class...

```
Date = System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDateTime("2012-09-03T06:35:31Z", XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Local);
```

You will need to change the XmlDateTimeSerializationMode to the appropriate value.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend converting to local time. If I took this approach (I might if I was doing some XML stuff anyway), I'd use `XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Universal` to avoid confusion or different behaviour with daylight savings, then convert to local if needed, as needed. Incidentally ISO 8601 isn't just in XML. Indeed, it was around since the 80s and built on earlier standards from the 70s, while XML wasn't invented until the 90s.

Comment: @JonHanna Very good points.  +1 for providing a good addendum to my answer.